# How to use fuse4x on Mac?

Tags: macos, fuse, ext4

I did

```
brew install fuse4x
```

I can see `fuse4x` and `fuse4x-kext` packages are installed.

When I try a basic mount it doesn't work:

```
➜  ~  mkdir ~/testusb
➜  ~  mount -t fuse4x -r /dev/disk1 ~/testusb
mount: exec /System/Library/Filesystems/fuse4x.fs/Contents/Resources/mount_fuse4x for /Users/kurt/testusb: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Fuse is just the system which allows filesystems to be plugged into userspace. Fuse itself is not a filesystem that can be used to mount anything. You need to install a filesystem that uses Fuse, like ntfs-3g.

Comment: Is there another brew package that I need?

Comment: Well, you need *a filesystem*. Fuse is not a filesystem. What do you think "mount a Fuse folder" is supposed to do?

Comment: How do I get the ext4 filesystem that works with fuse4x?